# Apollo onError forward(operation) not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo-client

I used the example form the Apollo docs:

```
onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError, operation, forward }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors) {
    for (let err of graphQLErrors) {
      switch (err.extensions.code) {
        // Apollo Server sets code to UNAUTHENTICATED
        // when an AuthenticationError is thrown in a resolver
        case 'UNAUTHENTICATED':

          // Modify the operation context with a new token
          const oldHeaders = operation.getContext().headers;
          operation.setContext({
            headers: {
              ...oldHeaders,
              authorization: getNewToken(),
            },
          });
          // Retry the request, returning the new observable
          return forward(operation);      }
    }
  }

  // To retry on network errors, we recommend the RetryLink
  // instead of the onError link. This just logs the error.
  if (networkError) {
    console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
  }
});
```

But nothing happens. The second request never works. Maybe it's problem with react native?

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
export const logoutLink = onError(({ networkError, operation, forward }) => {
  if (networkError?.statusCode === 401) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      (async () => {
        try {
          const newToken = await getToken();

      // Modify the operation context with a new token
      const oldHeaders = operation.getContext().headers;

      operation.setContext({
        headers: {
          ...oldHeaders,
          authorization: `Bearer ${newToken}`,
        },
      });

      const subscriber = {
        next: observer.next.bind(observer),
        error: observer.error.bind(observer),
        complete: observer.complete.bind(observer),
      };

      // Retry last failed request
      forward(operation).subscribe(subscriber);
    } catch (error) {
      observer.error(error);
    }
  })();
});
  }
});
```

Comment: This approach working fine. The Apollo doc example not run properly.